How to use my substring column to join a subquery to the parent query
I have a table which contains a data field of assorted IDs written in plain text.



Other_ID
Data
Date




123
user_id:098; metdata:[ID: 6482]
2024-10-13


456
user_id:754; metdata:[ID: 0743]
2024-10-12


123
user_id:098; metdata:[ID: 6482]
2024-10-01



I want to pull the ID and use that ID to add a subquery to my SELECT statement to find a max date and using the matching IDs to marry it. I am not having trouble pulling the ID, but I can't match the ID I just pulled to find the max date for each in the subquery. I thought maybe I needed to pull the substring portion into the subquery after max date in the select statement but that didn't work either and I get an error: Unsupported: Scalar subquery with multi-column SELECT clause.
SELECT 
    table2.org_name,
    table3.user_email,
    SUBSTRING(table1.data, CHARINDEX('metadata', table1.data), 5) as object_id,
    (SELECT MAX(datetime)
        FROM table1 
        WHERE SUBSTRING(table.data, CHARINDEX('metadata', table.data), 5) = pp.id AND event_type LIKE 'created-object' AND datetime > '2024-10-08') 
        as most_recent_created
FROM 
    table1
    LEFT JOIN pp ON ie_presentation_id = pp.id
    
    ...LEFT JOIN table2, LEFT JOIN table3 ... etc

I would expect it to spit back something like:



id
max_date




6482
2024-10-13


456
2024-10-12




CHARINDEX('metadata', data) gives you where the text metadata starts (I am assuming that you typed the sample data in your question incorrectly metdata...); that would be 14? then substring(data, 14,5)  would give you metad; are you sure you are able to get the id in object_id? In any case if the pp.id is an integer, and the result of substring is a string, there could be leading blanks in the latter; you need to trim them off before comparing. Also, use aliases for table1 in the main query and table1 in the subquery to be able to distinguish: what is table in table.data?

using a CTE for testing data:
with table1(other_id, data, date) as (
    select * from values
    (123, 'user_id:098; metdata:[ID: 6482]', '2024-10-13'::date),
    (456, 'user_id:754; metdata:[ID: 0743]', '2024-10-12'::date),
    (123, 'user_id:098; metdata:[ID: 6482]', '2024-10-01'::date)
)

you can simply use REGEXP_SUBSTR to pull out the ID, and then group on that:
select
    regexp_substr(t.data, '.*\\[ID:(.*)\\].*', 1,1,'e',1) as id
    ,max(t.date) as max_date
from table1 as t
group by 1 order by 1;

giving:



ID
MAX_DATE




0743
2024-10-12


6482
2024-10-13



Thus you can then push that into it's own CTE (or sub-select) and join to that:
like:
with table1(other_id, data, date) as (
    select * from values
    (123, 'user_id:098; metdata:[ID: 6482]', '2024-10-13'::date),
    (456, 'user_id:754; metdata:[ID: 0743]', '2024-10-12'::date),
    (123, 'user_id:098; metdata:[ID: 6482]', '2024-10-01'::date)
), max_date_per_sub_id as (
    select
        regexp_substr(t.data, '.*\\[ID:(.*)\\].*', 1,1,'e',1) as id
        ,max(t.date) as max_date
    from table1 as t
    WHERE event_type LIKE 'created-object' 
        AND datetime > '2024-10-08'
    group by 1;
)
SELECT 
    table2.org_name,
    table3.user_email,
    SUBSTRING(table1.data, CHARINDEX('metadata', table1.data), 5) as object_id,
    xx.max_date as most_recent_created
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN pp 
    ON ie_presentation_id = pp.id
LEFT JOIN max_date_per_sub_id as xx
    ON xx.id = p.id
...
LEFT JOIN table2, 
LEFT JOIN table3 
... etc
;

